# XMPPFramework - How to use Presence Priority?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, user-presence

I'm working on an iOS app with XMPPFramework and Openfire Server. I work with a book to implement it, but there are some parts I don't understand because the book makes references to Google Talk and I can't figure out what to do in those methods:

The first one is about presence, here is the code that is implemented in the book:

```
-(void)goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    NSString *domain = [self.xmppStream.myJID domain];

    // Google set their presence priority to 24, so we do the same to be compatible.

    if ([domain isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"] || [domain isEqualToString:@"gtalk.com"]) 
    {
        NSXMLElement *priority = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"priority" stringValue:@"24"];
        [presence addChild:priority];
    }

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
    [self.rootViewController updateStatus:@"online"];
}
```

As I'm working on localhost with my own server name, I don't know exactly what to do with presence or if Openfire have a value for the presence priority.

Comment: You shouldn't touch priority until you are not using multiple devices, just send empty `presence` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks vitalyster!!!!

Comment: @vitalyster Do you mean don't touch priority until you ARE USING multiple devices?